# Range query on BigDecimal in Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate-search

I am trying to do a range query on an entity field of type BigDecimal but couldn't make it work. This is what I've done so far.

This is the entity class.

```
public class Deal {
    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    @Field(name = "budget_Sort", store = Store.YES, normalizer= @Normalizer(definition = SearchConstants.LOWER_CASE_NORMALIZER))
    @FieldBridge(impl = BigDecimalNumericFieldBridge.class)
    @SortableField(forField = "budget_Sort")
    @Column(name = "BUDGET", precision = 10, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal budget = new BigDecimal(0);

    //other fields and methods omitted for brevity
}
```

The custom FieldBridge for BigDecimal is as follows. I chose type DOUBLE as the converted type.

```
public class BigDecimalNumericFieldBridge implements MetadataProvidingFieldBridge, TwoWayFieldBridge {

    private static final BigDecimal storeFactor = BigDecimal.valueOf( 100 );

    @Override
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        if ( value != null ) {
            BigDecimal decimalValue = (BigDecimal) value;
            Double indexedValue = decimalValue.multiply( storeFactor ).doubleValue();
            luceneOptions.addNumericFieldToDocument( name, indexedValue, document );
            luceneOptions.addNumericDocValuesFieldToDocument(name, indexedValue, document);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(String name, Document document) {
        String fromLucene = document.get( name );
        if (Objects.nonNull(fromLucene)) {
            BigDecimal storedBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(fromLucene);
            return storedBigDecimal.divide(storeFactor);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object object) {
        return object.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder builder) {
        builder.field( name, FieldType.DOUBLE );
    }
}
```

I then defined a class Range to pass lower bound, upper bound and field data type.

```
public class Range {
    private String lowerBound;
    private String upperBound;
    private String dataType;
}
```

And created the following object to test this range query.

`Range budgetRange = new Range("9500", "10500",SearchConstants.BIGDECIMAL);`

The actual query building logic is as follows.

````
    protected Query rangeFilterBuilder(String key, String field) {
        Query rangeQuery = null;
        String lowerBound = searchRequest.getRangeFilters().get(key).getLowerBound();
        String upperBound = searchRequest.getRangeFilters().get(key).getUpperBound();
        String dataType = searchRequest.getRangeFilters().get(key).getDataType();
        switch (dataType) {
            case SearchConstants.INTEGER:
                rangeQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField(field).from(Integer.valueOf(lowerBound)).to(Integer.valueOf(upperBound)).createQuery();
                break;
            case SearchConstants.LONG:
                rangeQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField(field).from(Long.valueOf(lowerBound)).to(Long.valueOf(upperBound)).createQuery();
                break;
            case SearchConstants.DOUBLE:
                rangeQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField(field).from(Double.valueOf(lowerBound)).to(Double.valueOf(upperBound)).createQuery();
                break;
            case SearchConstants.STRING:
                rangeQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField(field).from((lowerBound)).to(upperBound).createQuery();
                break;
            case SearchConstants.DATE:
                rangeQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField(field).from(LocalDateTime.parse(lowerBound)).to(LocalDateTime.parse(upperBound)).createQuery();
                break;
            case SearchConstants.BIGDECIMAL:
                rangeQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField(field).from(Double.valueOf(lowerBound)).to(Double.valueOf(upperBound)).createQuery();
        }
        return rangeQuery;
    }```

This always return 0 matching result regardless of the range. I've tried other fields of type int or long and they work as expected. Is there something that I missed for BigDecimal range query?
````

Comment: Which version of Hibernate Search are you using? Upgrading to 5.11.2 might help, there's been problems with this in older versions (5.6/5.7, I believe).

Comment: I am using 5.11.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're multiplying the value by 100 when indexing, but not when querying. So when you search for value `42`, the range `[40, 45]` won't match, but the range `[4000, 4500]` will.

The solution would be to multiply the bounds by 100 in your function, for the "BigDecimal" case:

```
        switch (dataType) {
            case SearchConstants.INTEGER:
                rangeQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField(field).from(Integer.valueOf(lowerBound)).to(Integer.valueOf(upperBound)).createQuery();
                break;
            case SearchConstants.LONG:
                rangeQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField(field).from(Long.valueOf(lowerBound)).to(Long.valueOf(upperBound)).createQuery();
                break;
            case SearchConstants.DOUBLE:
                rangeQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField(field).from(Double.valueOf(lowerBound)).to(Double.valueOf(upperBound)).createQuery();
                break;
            case SearchConstants.STRING:
                rangeQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField(field).from((lowerBound)).to(upperBound).createQuery();
                break;
            case SearchConstants.DATE:
                rangeQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField(field).from(LocalDateTime.parse(lowerBound)).to(LocalDateTime.parse(upperBound)).createQuery();
                break;
            case SearchConstants.BIGDECIMAL:
                rangeQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField(field).from(Double.valueOf(lowerBound) * 100.0).to(Double.valueOf(upperBound) * 100.0).createQuery();
        }
```

By the way, I really think your function should parse the number as a `BigDecimal`, not a `Double`, in the `BigDecimal` case. Then you can multiply it, and then convert it to `Double`, similarly to what you did in your function.

Also, you'll probably want to use `Long` instead of `Double` when indexing (and querying) a scaled `BigDecimal`: you'll get more performance and will be sure that the indexed number is exactly the one you want (no rounding). You don't need the range of a `double` for monetary amounts anyway, unless you're dealing with amounts higher than the total value of all assets on earth :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Wouldn't it be nice if I am actually dealing with that much money? ^^. Anyway, I changed my code based on your suggestion and it works now. Thank you very much!